# Does the series $\sum$$(n!)^2/(2n)!$ diverge or converge?

Tags: calculus

Does the series: $$\sum \frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}$$ converge or diverge?

I used the ratio test, and got an end result as $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ $\frac{n+1}{2}$ which would make it divergent but i know it's convergent. Am i using the right test?

Comment: Is it $(2n)!$ or $2 n!$?

Comment: (2n)! my apologies, but your hint was correct :)

Comment: No problem. I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** You can use the ratio test.

$$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{1}{2}\,{\frac {n+1}{2\,n+1}}. $$

Comment: sorry i meant ratio

Comment: ah this helped me out! thanks a ton !!! :)

Comment: @lawlipopL No problem. You had the right approach.

Answer (score 5):

Your ratio test is incorrect. Note that
$$\dfrac{\dbinom{2n}n}{\dbinom{2n+2}{n+1}} = \dfrac{(2n)!}{n! \cdot n!} \dfrac{(n+1)! (n+1)!}{(2n+2)!} = \dfrac{(n+1)^2}{2(n+1)(2n+1)} = \dfrac{n+1}{2(2n+1)}$$
Hence, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\dbinom{2n}n}{\dbinom{2n+2}{n+1}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{n+1}{2(2n+1)} = \dfrac14 < 1$$

Alternatively, from Stirling, we have that the binomial coefficient goes as
$$\dbinom{2n}n \sim \dfrac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$$

You should be able to conclude from either whether the series converges or diverges from this.

Comment: yea this is how i was trying to do it, i realized i was expanding the (2n+2)! all wrong! thank you!! :)

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty easy to show (without Stirling) that $$\binom {2n}{n}\geq \frac{4^n}{2n+1}$$

So $$\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!} < \frac{2n+1}{4^n}$$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, consider that for $n\geq2$ we have
$$\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}={2n\choose n}\geq{2n\choose2}=\frac{(2n)(2n-1)}{2}>n^2$$